# selenium facebook comment reply

Tags: python, xml, facebook, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to reply to facebook comments using selenium and python.
I've been able to select the field using

```
 find_elements_by_css_selector(".UFIAddCommentInput")
```

But I can't post text using the send_keys method. Heres a simplified structure of the comment html for facebook:

```
<div><input tabindex="-1" name="add_comment_text">
<div class="UFIAddCommentInput _1osb _5yk1"><div class="_5yk2">
<div class="_5yw9"><div class="_5ywb">
<div class="_3br6">Write a comment...</div></div>
<div class="_5ywa">
<div title="Write a comment..." role="combobox"       

 class="_54z"contenteditable="true">
<div data-contents="true">
 <div class="_209g _2vxa">
```

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly fine. The only catch being, clear the `div` everytime before you begin to type a new comment.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

f = webdriver.Firefox()
f.get("https://facebook.com")

# Skipping the logging in and going to a particular post part.

# The selector I used correspond to id of the post and 
# class of the div that contains editable text part
e = f.find_element_by_css_selector("div#u_jsonp_8_q div._54-z")
e.send_keys("bob")
e.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
e.clear()

e.send_keys("kevin")
e.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
e.clear()
```

Comment: I've tried your solution but I'm getting "NoSuchElementException"

Comment: Tried changing the class and id?

Comment: Yeah I tried with all the classes. I think your comment is on to something because you use the ".54-z" class which is set to be editable. But I can't locate it directly with find_element_by_class. I tried adding dots to your code as well since there is a space between json_8_q and div. Still not working :(

Comment: You don't have to add "dots" between the id and the div, there is supposed to be a space in between.

The id I have used here is the id of the block as you see in the screenshot and the class name is name of the class for the div that houses the editable content.


https://www.dropbox.com/s/rgof141r4gx7x7i/Screen%20Shot%202015-12-09%20at%2011.15.10.png?dl=0

Comment: In this case `div#u_1f_17 div._57w`

Comment: If you prefer `xpath` use `f.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='u_1f_17']/div[@class='_57w _5vsi']")`. Please note, `xpath` would require you to write the entire class/id selector whichever you choose.

Comment: but these divs and class names keeps changing right.. ?

Comment: Well yes! There should be a good rule how they do, but that would require understanding the way the UI is programmed to behave. In any case, try running the tests a few times and see what result it gives.

Comment: hmm I've found solutions that select the _54-z class with the firepath. I've tried a dynamic solution based on your post:  "div[id*='u_'] div._54-z" . It works with firefinder plugin but not with selenium

Comment: Sure. xpath: .//*[contains(@id,'u_') and contains(@class,'uiUfi') ]//*[ contains(@class,'UFIInputContainer')]//*[ contains(@class,'AddCommentInput')]//*[ contains(@class,'_54')]

Comment: Sure. xpath: driver.find_elements_by_xpath(.//*[contains(@id,'u_') and contains(@class,'uiUfi') ]//*[ contains(@class,'UFIInputContainer')]//*[ contains(@class,'AddCommentInput')]//*[ contains(@class,'_54')])         then css solution: driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('[title=Write'])  (found the _54-z class with firepath )  or alternatively:  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[id*='u_][class*='uiUfI'] div[class='_54-z'])

Comment: I have a very small issue with this selector of yours. I see you have put a period before the first `//`, could you try removing it and instead of `*` can you try using the tag name?

For css instead of using the word `class` and `id` you should most probably use `.` and `#` respectively.

Give it a try and let me know what happens.

Comment: problem is that with "#" I can't use the "contains" or " *= " function and without this it's not dynamic. Facebook randomize their div ids.. I compared a lot of ids for the container of the comments and I found that the only common characters they all have is "u_8" . If I use f.ex "div#u_jsonp_841" that would only be valid if I knew the id. But every session selenium starts the ids will be different. I  want my program to find any commentfield on a facebook page and post to it.

Comment: From my experience I have seen that if class is something like `<div class="titi toto tata">` you can use `div[class*='toto']` but not `div[class*='t']`. The problem that you face is a bit different where you want to find a pattern inside the class definition. It should work just fine, but i am really not sure why it is not working for you.

Comment: Well I tried working on this again and I got this as error `Uncaught Error: <![EX[["Tried to get element with id of \"%s\" but it is not present on the page.","a._48pw"]]]>`